# How to access params in getStaticPaths?

Tags: javascript, next.js

I have a Next.js app and the CMS is Contentful.

File structure relevant for this question is as follows:

```
pages
-[category]
  -[slug].js
```

What I want to do is access the value of category when a users visits category/slug.

Right now I am hardcoding category. Is there any way I can access category using params?

```
const category = 'mains';

export async function getStaticPaths() {
    let data = await client.getEntries({ content_type: category });
    return {
        paths: data.items.map((path) => ({
            params: { category: category, slug: path.fields.slug }
        })),
        fallback: false
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getStaticPaths` are used for prerendering paths i.e before the app is deployed. You need to use `getStaticProps` for rendering on-demand, there, you will have a `context.params` object with all the params (`ctx.params.category`, `ctx.params.slug`)